# JQuery $(this).find("#id").text("text") not changing text

Tags: javascript, jquery, element

I'm looping through all elements of a certain class on a page and editing the text of an  tag in that class with a certain id. I'm referencing the element with `$(this).find('#time')` and trying to change the text of that object using `$(this).find('#time').text("test")`, but the the text of the element isn't changing and I can't figure out why.

EDIT:
`$('.box').each(function(i, obj){}` This is what the loop is, the odd thing is that when i simply reference the text with `$(this).find('#time').text()` i receive the correct output. But the text won't change when using `.text()`.

Here is the code im using to change the object text:

```
var time = response.substring(7, 15);
var user = response.substring(16, response.length);
$(this).find('#time').text(time);
$(this).find('#name').text(response.substring(user));
```

Game Page

```
<div class="box">
    <h1>&#36;{{ game_object.amount }}</h1>
    <h2 id="time">{{ game_object.start_time}}</h2>
    <p id="name">{{ game_object.current_top_user }}</p>
    <a href="{% url 'game_page' game.pk %}" class="click_play">CLICK NOW</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post a little more code? can try to get a working example going.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the looping code (so that we can tell what `this` is) and the relevant HTML.

Comment: What is the context of "this" here?

Comment: Either your `this` is not what you think it is, or there is no element with id "time" inside of it. I made a working fiddle if things are scoped correctly that works... https://jsfiddle.net/d5gtp9sn/

Comment: I agree with the other comments about adding the code. I think the issue has to do with the wrong context being assumed

Comment: @jas7457 Edited with more info.

Comment: So two things... 1. Are you sure `time` actually evaluates to something? 2. You are looping through your `.box`es and each of them has a `#text` inside of it? You are not meant to have more than one instance of an id. Maybe jQuery is failing because there are multiple elements with the same id and it doesn't know which one it should grab? Just a guess.

Comment: @jas7457 I'm working on a Django project and every box represents a different game, with the time and name specific to that game. I'll add the full code for that HTML page so that you can see what I mean. There are multiple elements with the name ID also though, and those are being evaluated correctly as well because I set two different test names in my database to test it with and they evaluate correctly on the page when the site is live, I simply can't edit or change the value.

Answer (score -4):

Try to use .html

```
$(this).find('#time').html("test")
```

or maybe this can help you:

```
$('body').find('#time').text('test');
```

Because the ID of an element must to be unique

Comment: Why would that work if `.text()` didn't? (Also, what if they specifically want to set text and not html?)

Comment: I don't think the OP can find the time to do that!
--Sorry, I couldn't resist.

Comment: :'( okeyyyyyyyy

Comment: Using html wouldn't be any more fruitful than using text. Also, why even do $('body').find instead of just $('#find')? The find is normally used to scope inside of a matched jQuery element, calling .find on body defeats that purpose.

Comment: jas7457 meant `$('#time')`. No point first selecting the `'body'` and then using `.find()` when `$('#time')` does it in one step.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I did mean $('#time');

Comment: I can't just use $('#time') because there are multiple elements on the page with the ID of time, all specific to the .box element that they are within. Unless I have a complete misunderstanding of how $() works.